# excel files loop

Tags: loops, excel, vba

In my excel sheet I'm using formulas which referring to external sheets.
Instead of manually changing the value in cell `E7` (where I insert name of external sheet), I want to write an macro to open all of external sheets, change reference value in `E7` and copy the generated values.

Unfortunately my code does't work - Excel can't "see" the values in the external sheet.
What should I change?

---

```
Sub lista_plik()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    folder = "path_here"
    folder2 = folder & "*.xlsx"

    arkusz = Dir(folder2)

    Do While arkusz <> ""
        x = x + 1
        Range("E7").Value = Replace(arkusz, ".xlsx", "")
        arkusz = folder & arkusz

        Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(arkusz)
''''''''''''''''''''
HERE CODE TO COPY VALUES
'''''''''''''''''''''''
        oWB.Close
        arkusz = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear (to me at least) what you are looking to do, and what you are missing here. `E7` will be updated - and overwritten - with each new worknook name (not sheet) that you open. What values do you want copied accross? And to the same sheet, new sheet etc? Please post more info

Comment: Why not open the other wb in the same Excel session?  Also, you should qualify all your Range()'s with the relevant workbook, otherwise confusion will result...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with brettdj, it is difficult to know what you are trying to achieve.

Chris has fixed two of your errors but without explaining the second correction which I suspect is the cause of the problem.

In your code you use `Range("E7").Value`.  This refers to cell E7 within the active sheet of the active workbook.  Chris has changed this to `oWS.Range("E7").Value`, which is an improvement, but oWS has not been initialised so its not enough.

My experience of working with multiple workbooks is that you must keep total control.  I suspect your error is that Excel is looking at the wrong E7.  The steps below will eliminate that and any similar errors.

**Step 1**

Make sure there is only one workbook open at the beginning by checking that `WorkBooks.Count = 1`.  If you permit two or more workbooks being open, you will need code to check that the active workbook is the one you want.  So something like:

```
If WorkBooks.Count > 1 Then
  Call MsgBox("Please close other workbooks then try again.", vbYesOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If
```

**Step 2**

Before you open any other workbook, record which is the master workbook.

```
Dim WBkMaster As WorkBook

WBkMaster = ActiveWorkBook
```

**Step 3**

Always refer to workbooks and worksheets explicitly.  For example:

```
With WBkMaster
  With Sheets("x1")
    .Range("E7").Value = ...
    ' Extract data from Sheet x1 to variables here
  End With
  With Sheets("x2")
    ' Extract data from Sheet x2 to variables here
  End With
End With

Set WBkDestination = Application.Workbooks.Open(arkusz)

With WBkDestination
  With Sheets("x3")
    ' Save data for Sheet x3 from variables here
  End With
  With Sheets("x4")
    ' Save data for Sheet x4 from variables here
  End With
  . Close
End With
oWB = Nothing   ' Ensure no reference to closed workbook
```

There are other approaches to copying data between worksheets and workbooks but you do not give enough information to recommend which approach would be the most appropriate.  The key issue is that you must be totally explicit about which sheet and which workbook you want addressed.

Comment: +1 really clear and nicely explained. I am not sure step 1 is needed in this case though

Comment: @JMax. Perhaps you are more careful than me. I have checked my destination workbooks and have forgotten to close them before running a macro which caused damage because the wrong workbook was active. I often keep macros I do not want my users to see in a separate workbook so this is a regular risk that I wish to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in VBA you don't need to declare an instance of `Excwl`.  Change to:

```
Sub lista_plik()
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Set oWs = ActiveSheet

    folder = "path_here\"
    folder2 = folder & "*.xlsx"

    arkusz = Dir(folder2)

    Do While arkusz <> ""
        x = x + 1
        oWs.Range("E7").Value = Replace(arkusz, ".xlsx", "")
        arkusz = folder & arkusz

        Set oWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(arkusz)
''''''''''''''''''''
'HERE CODE TO COPY VALUES
'''''''''''''''''''''''
        oWB.Close
        arkusz = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note: I'm not entierly sure which workbooks cell `E7` you are refering to, here I assume its in the active workbook.