# Excel VBA Do While loop in a directory folder and rows count

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 questions with my coding. Please bear with me since I'm not an expert on this.

1. Ws2.range("B6:Y" & lrow1).copy - doesn't seem to work the way I wanted it to be. It copies cells only from B1:Y6 but the intention is to copy cells starting ffrom B6:Y until the last row.
2. Dir Do while loops only on one file even though I have multiple files on the specified folder path. Thus, creating an infinite loop.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub conso()
Dim folder As String, consofolder As String
Dim files As String, consofile As String
Dim dateyear As String, team As String
Dim strfile As String, newdate As String
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim lrow1 As Long, lrow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

dateyear = Range("A2").Value
newdate = Format(dateyear, "mmmm yyyy")
team = Range("B2").Value
folder = Range("C2").Value
consofolder = folder & newdate & "\" & team
consofile = "conso "
files = Dir(consofolder & "\*.xlsm")
strfile = consofolder & "\" & consofile & team & " - " & newdate & ".xlsm"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Workbooks.Open Filename:=folder & "\" & "conso conso" & ".xlsm"
Set wb1 = Workbooks("conso conso.xlsm")
wb1.Activate
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Input")
If Len(Dir(strfile)) = 0 Then

    GoTo conso
Else
    MsgBox "Conso already in place"
    Exit Sub
End If
conso:
Do While files <> ""
    Debug.Print files

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=consofolder & "\" & files
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(files)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Input")
    With wb2
        With Worksheets("Input")
            lrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    End With
    ws2.Range("B6:Y" & lrow1).Copy
    wb1.Activate
    With wb1
        With Worksheets("Input")
            lrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    End With
    ws1.Range("B" & lrow2).PasteSpecial
    wb2.Close
    files = Dir(consofolder & "\*.xlsm")

    Set wb2 = Nothing
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `Ws2.range("B6:Y" & lrow1).copy ... copies cells only from B1:Y6`  that will happen if `lrow1` equals 1.  Check the contents of the column you're getting the last row from

Comment: There are lots of examples of using Dir to iterate a folder on SO. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8787868/445425)

Comment: You are also doing a lot of implicit Active Book/Sheet/Range references which you don't need to do.  These may cause you to reference the wrong objects